# How to get an SQS batch from a producer lambda to the consumer lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

A producer AWS lambda pushes a batch of e.g. 3 messages using sqs.sendMessageBatch() into a AWS SQS standard queue. The consumer AWS lambda however gets called 3 times for each entry of the original SQS batch.

How can I get the SQS batch from the producer batch to the consumer batch in its entity?

sqs.sendMessageBatch()

The entire message batch triggers the lambda. The event of the SQS consumer lambda receives the entire input batch.

**I have set the batch size at the consumer lambda to the default of 10. The producer lambda sends a batch containing 3 messages (entries). What I observe is that the consumer lambda get's invoked 3 times for each message in the batch:**

```
// PRODUCER
async function sendMessageBatch(params) {
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        sqs.sendMessageBatch(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                rej(err);
            } else {
                res(data);
            }
        });
    });
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    var transaction;
    var entries = [];
    var entry;
    var transactions = await scan(sparams);
    // e.g. 3 messages
    for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
        transaction = transactions[i];
        console.log("TX: " + JSON.stringify(transaction));
        var msgBody = JSON.stringify({
            asset: transaction.asset,
            lastUpdatedAt: transaction.lastUpdatedAt,
            to: transaction.to,
            qty: transaction.qty,

        });
        entry = {
            Id: uuidv1(),
            MessageBody: msgBody,
            DelaySeconds: 0
        };
        entries.push(entry);
    }

    if (entries.length) {
        console.log("Entries: " + JSON.stringify(entries));
        var sendMessageBatchParams = {
            Entries: entries,
            QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
        };
        await sendMessageBatch(sendMessageBatchParams);
    }
    return {};
}

//CONSUMER
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // expected: 3 messages in event.Records (batch)
    for (var record of event.Records) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure the batch size correctly for the consumer?

Comment: check long polling and request batching on the consumer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a really great article [here on the serverless blog](https://serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-sqs-serverless-integration/#batch-size-and-error-handling-with-the-sqs-integration), about Lambda and SQS integration, with a specific section addressing batch processing.

Make sure you set the batchSize (maximum number of messages to be processed) correctly. <s>If exactly one time delivery is important, make sure your queue is a FIFO queue, otherwise</s> make sure you take note of the second point in planning for resiliency by making sure processing is idempotent.

Comment: FYI FIFO queues don't support Lambda function triggers.. Please adapt your answer. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html

Comment: Nice catch, we use a lot of FIFO queues and I totally forgot this point. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi all. Thank you very much for your support so far. I've read the proposed interesting article on the implementation of SQS. I have specified my question above with some code sample. I hope that shows the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

FIFO queue is supported as triggering event for lambda

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/#:~:text=You%20can%20get%20started%20with,or%20AWS%20SDK%20for%20Lambda.&text=You%20pay%20only%20for%20the,used%20to%20process%20your%20messages](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20get%20started%20with,or%20AWS%20SDK%20for%20Lambda.&text=You%20pay%20only%20for%20the,used%20to%20process%20your%20messages).

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless